# ImportError: No module named sklearn.feature_extraction.text

Tags: python, pacman-package-manager

I use from `python 2.7` and `pacman` package manager, and install sclearn with it.
but when i have an ImportError:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sklearn.feature_extraction.text
```

How i can fix this error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For python 2, you should be able to use this command to install using pacman:

> pacman -S python2-scikit-learn

Make sure the package name has the number "2" in it.

As per [scikit-learn's installation guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html), another way to install it is using pip:

> pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" -U scikit-learn

Answer (score 8):

When installing on Ubuntu Linux you have to have to install dependencies first using apt-get, then use a pip install otherwise the normal pip install of scikit-learn won't work properly. See below:

**Step 1: Make sure apt-get is updated**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Step 2: Install dependencies**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools python-numpy python-scipy libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base
```

**Step 3: pip install Scikit Learn**

```
pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" -U scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Install python 2.7 from python home page

   - I installed 2.7.14 (latest by 22/07/2018)
2. PIP is by default available in C:\Python27\scripts 
   Added these locations (C:\Python27\ & C:\Python27\scripts) to system path variable  (Windows10 machine)
3. Install scikit-learn package

   > pip install -U scikit-learn

We can see the scikit learn package library at c:\python27\lib\site-packages
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn
4. Install numpy and scipy as these 2 are prerequisites for scikit-learn

> pip install numpy
>
> pip install scipy

C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\